# How Do i fix this and get my page indicator running in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am making an APP gui in flutter, i have made 4 pages and made them accessible by sliding using pageview widget.
this is my homepage which has the pageview widget. The error shows "Positional arguments must occur before named arguments.
Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments.dart(positional_after_named_argument)
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.dartextra_positional_arguments_could_be_named"
this is my code for home page

```
import 'package:final_project/pages/pages1.dart';
import 'package:final_project/pages/pages2.dart';
import 'package:final_project/pages/pages3.dart';
import 'package:final_project/pages/pages4.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, keepPage: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: PageView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: const [pagg1(), pagg2(), pagg3(), pagg4()]),
          SmoothPageIndicator(controller: _controller, count: 4);
    );
  }
}
```

The homepage

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Column` on body to have multi-child,

```dart
 body: Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: PageView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: const [pagg1(), pagg2(), pagg3(), pagg4()]),
    ),
    SmoothPageIndicator(controller: _controller, count: 4)
  ],
)
```

Comment: Glad to help you out. You can check more about [ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)